# How to code a player collecting dots in pacman like game?

Tags: java

I'm stuck on an assignment and was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction. We are supposed to create a pacman like game and I am stuck on the following question:

The move() method should also tell the player to collect a dot if possible. The player can collect a dot only if the player is at the same position as the dot. 
When the player collects a dot, the player’s “collectedDots” count should be increased by 1, and the dot should disappear. When a dot disappears, its “exists” field should be set to false.

I know that I am supposed to create a disappear method for the Dot class and use the 'if' statement within the method to turn the 'exists' field from true to false if the player is in the same position as the dot. We weren't asked previously to create a Position method for any of the classes, all we have so far are; Dot class: Fields int x, int y and boolean exists = true. Constructor and toString. Game class: Fields player, dot1, dot2, dot3. Constructor. Move method and toString method. Player class: Fields int x, int y, int collectedDots. Constructor. Collected dots method only stating that collectedDots = 0. Set and Get methods and toString method. So, I'm not sure what code needs to be in the Disappear method and what to write in the move method either without a Position class. Please help.

Comment: well, what are the x and y fields for both the dot and player if not positions?

Comment: they are but I'm not sure how to write that under an if statement. if (player.getX() == ?
it's not making sense to me. Should I add a Get method for the Dot class?

Comment: Yes, I think somehow you should reach the coordinates of both the player and the dot. And you are totally right, the most beautiful solution consists of building a class for Position, which can be used by both dot and player.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for every call of the move method whether there is a dot at the position you're gonna move to. So what you do is kind of in the move method, after you calculated and set the new position of a player:

```
for (Dot dot: dots) {
    if (dot.X == player.X && dot.Y == player.Y) {
        dot.Disappear;
        player.collectedDots = player.collectedDots+1;
    }
}
```

That's basically it, but you need to kind of take into account that your dot and player probably have width and height (if a collision is meant to happen when the dot and the player overlap but are not in exactly the same position).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to get at initially. We still have one more tutorial before the assignment due date that will help us finish it but I just wanted to finish it early. Thanks for the tip!